# How to set text to a label on keyboard key press in JavaFX application?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm making JavaFX application with Scene Builder. I have Main Class that launch Controller with main window.

I have a label in the Controller class

I need to assign keyboard key press in main window.

Example: if I press '1' on keyboard the text of a label should be set as "key 1 is pressed.

If I press "2" on keyboard the text should be set as "key 2 is pressed"

**How Can I do that?**

I've tried  to use this code in initialize method, but nothing happens:

```
  category1.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
    KeyCode kc = ke.getCode();
    if((kc.equals(KeyCode.D))) {
      category1.setText("Key D is pressed");
    }
  }
});
```

**Main Class:**
package src.card;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }


  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    try {

      Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("resources/fxml/card.fxml"));
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1600, 600);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
      primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
      primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
      primaryStage.setResizable(true);

      primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("src/card/resources/logo-icon.png"));
      primaryStage.show();

      //adding resize and drag primary stage
      ResizeHelper.addResizeListener(primaryStage);


      //assign ALT+ENTER to maximize window
      final KeyCombination kb = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
      scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
          if (kb.match(event)) {
            primaryStage.setMaximized(!primaryStage.isMaximized());
            primaryStage.setResizable(true);
            Controller cont = Context.getInstance().getController();
            if (!primaryStage.isMaximized()) {
              cont.getBtnFont().setPrefWidth(20);
              cont.getBtnPalette().setPrefWidth(20);
              cont.getBtnQuestCards().setPrefWidth(20);
              cont.getBtnNonQuestCards().setPrefWidth(20);

            } else if (primaryStage.isMaximized()){
              cont.getBtnFont().setPrefWidth(50);
              cont.getBtnPalette().setPrefWidth(50);
              cont.getBtnQuestCards().setPrefWidth(50);
              cont.getBtnNonQuestCards().setPrefWidth(50
              );
            }

          }
        }
      });

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
@FXML  private Label category1

@FXML public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    category1.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
        KeyCode kc = ke.getCode();
        if((kc.equals(KeyCode.D))) {
          category1.setText("Key D is pressed");
        }
      }
    });


    //register Controller in  Context Class
    Context.getInstance().setController(this);
  }
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried to use it in initialize method:

```
category1.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
        KeyCode kc = ke.getCode();
        if((kc.equals(KeyCode.D))) {
          category1.setText("Key D is pressed");
        }
      }
    });
```

and I got errors:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/IDEA%20Projects/CategoryCards/out/production/CategoryCards/src/card/resources/fxml/card.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
```

If I remove `getScene()` from category1  - everything is going fine and application launch

It seems when I use `getScene()` it try to get fxml file from out folder, not my main folder, but how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think that setting the label text is the problem here. I feel like having a label with a keypress event is.
My guess is that you should add the key press listener to the scene and not to the label.

Comment: @Link64 how can I do it in Controller? scene is initialized in Main class. Should I wrote the code with key press  in Main?

Comment: @kentforth You can retrieve the scene from any node which belongs to with the method `Node#getScene()`, then in your case, it could be `category1.getScene()` .

Comment: @Pagbo can you check my last edit?

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` because you load your FXML and then execute your `initialize` method before adding it to the scene, and then `category1.getScene()` is `null` in your initiliaze method.

Comment: @Pagbo where should I place  `category1.getScene()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by setting key press event(`setOnKeyPressed`) to parent of `Label`
instead of `Scene`. Trying to add event to `Scene` will give error because `initialize` will be called before creation of the `Scene`.

Let's say you have FXML file called `sample.fxml` and In that file you have `GridPane` having id `root` and a `Label` having id `category1`

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<GridPane fx:controller="Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" fx:id="root">
    <Label text="Category" fx:id="category1"/>
</GridPane>
```

And you have Controller class called `Controller`. To change label of `category1` when any key is pressed, first you have to set `category1` focus traversable by calling `setFocusTraversable` method on `category1` and passing `true`. And then you have to add key press event on `root`(parent of `category1`), As shown below

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable{
    
    @FXML private Label category1;
    @FXML private GridPane root;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
        category1.setFocusTraversable(true);
        root.setOnKeyPressed(this::handle);
    }
    
    private void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent){
        category1.setText("Key " + keyEvent.getCode().getName() + " is pressed");
    }
    
}
```

And here is simple version of `Main` class

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
}
```